# SSL Error when calling Parse.com cloud functions with iOS 8

Tags: ios, ssl, parse-platform

I sometimes get an error on iOS 8 when calling CloudCode functions. It only happens sometimes, and I have no idea why:

```
Error: Error Domain=Parse Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 100.)" UserInfo=0x17ed2150 

{   Code=100, 
    error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
    UserInfo=0x19d0c750 {
        NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 
        _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, 
        NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/1/functions/weshread,
        _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
        NSUnderlyingError=0x19de4f40 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.", 
        NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/1/functions/weshread
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Jack Cox pointed out Parse's TLS isn't up to snuff. But you just need to add an exception for the `api.parse.com` domain, and the exception only needs to accept the less secure ciphers. See this [Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016240-CH1-SW3) from Apple about App Transport Security.

Here's what needs to be added to your `Info.plist`:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>api.parse.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**UPDATE:** Parse sent out an email yesterday saying they'd be updating their certs on 8/11/2015, which should get rid of the need for this. I'll update my answer when that has happened.

Comment: How can we handle this exception with Alamofire?
I have tried your solution but still receiving the exception. (PS: Using iOS9)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Analytics servers do not support TLSv2 yet.  To temporarily work around this you need tell the iOS 9 app that it should do insecure connections.

Add the following entry to the info.plist file for your app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Ack! That's disabling all of ATS. All you need to do is add an exception for "api.parse.com" with NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy set to false.

Comment: Agreed, it's a quick and dirty work around. The best alternative is to lobby Parse to get TLSv2 working on their APIs.

Comment: I tried both NSAllowsArbitraryLoads & NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy in my Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0 project; and I STILL get the SSL error when attempting to contact Parse.com